# How to count a column in table_b and union on a mian select?

Tags: sql-server

I write a query below

```
SELECT sales_people_name 
,COUNT(amount_sales) AS total_sales
,SUM(price) AS total price
**mark1**

FROM order
group by sales_people_name
```

My intention is to add a nuw column from a table which name is "sale_shops" on **mark1**
which can count the number of shop belonging sales people.

How to achieve this outcome?

I tryed to left join to table but the consequence still is not my need.

Comment: *"I tryed [cite] to left join to table but the consequence still is not my need."* Why didn't it work? What was the attempt?

Comment: There are a lot of details you are not sharing here. For starters, that can't be the exact query you wrote as it would fail because the table name "order" would need to be wrapped in square brackets. In your question title you say something about table_b and union. Where are those tables in your question? We need a lot more information to be able to help here.

Comment: If i left join tabel_shops and count the number of sales people's shops, the number will be minor than the same number from table Order. It should be greater than the number from order table. because it count the total number of shops that belong to salespeople.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in the SELECT statement to count the number of shops belonging to sales people in table_b and then union it with the main query. Here's an example:

```
SELECT mark1.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_b WHERE sales_person = mark1.sales_person)             
as sale_shops
FROM mark1
UNION
SELECT mark2.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_b WHERE sales_person = mark2.sales_person) 
as sale_shops
FROM mark2
```

This will return all columns from mark1 and mark2 table and a new column named "sale_shops" which contains the count of shops belonging to the sales people in table_b.

Or you can join the table_b with mark1 and mark2 and use the COUNT() function

```
SELECT mark1.*, COUNT(table_b.sales_person) as sale_shops
FROM mark1
LEFT JOIN table_b ON mark1.sales_person = table_b.sales_person
GROUP BY mark1.sales_person
UNION
SELECT mark2.*, COUNT(table_b.sales_person) as sale_shops
FROM mark2
LEFT JOIN table_b ON mark2.sales_person = table_b.sales_person
GROUP BY mark2.sales_person
```